# STEAM unable to find Steam Games on another SSD

Tags: steam, ubuntu

So as of writing this STEAM does now show me the Steam Library on a different SSD. I was playing a game on Steam yesterday today for some bizarre reason all my games show the download + install icon. I selected Steam Settings then found the Steam Library Folders button. I clicked this and the Storage Manager appeared, showing only my main SSD. My alternative SSD specifically named Steam Games was missing.
I clicked the + button and then NOTHING happened!! (I am supposed top see a dialogue box with, Add a new Steam Library Folder).
probable rhetorical question but is the problem with the Steam app or is it with my own computer?
Any other options to resolve?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Is the SSD still recognized by your OS?

Comment: I have had this happen *once*, some time ago, where any of my libraries apart from the one marked "Local Drive (/)" (which is actually `~/.local/share/Steam`) had gone, however, adding the libraries back with the correct path meant they were all found again.

Comment: The SSD always shows on the taskbar auto-boot on startup. I can access the drive where all the STEAM games are located.  Last night i uninstalled STEAM, rebooted the computer then installed Steam Installer, STEAM and then all the add-ons. The dialogue box returns but the /mnt folder does not appear.

Comment: What version of Steam did you install? Was it the Flatpak version, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to fully close steam and re mount the drive. Also you may need to click on the option to create a new steam folder and it should reread the games and you should have access to them.